# Projectile is detecting both the wall and the "grunt" as a "grunt"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a projectile prefab that is being launched from the player and when it collides with a "boundary" it is supposed to destroy itself and when it hits a "grunt" it is supposed to destroy itself and the grunt. However when it hits a boundary it destroys itself and the boundaries' colliders. I created a custom tag script that allows me to assign multiple tags to a game object rather than only one.

Why is it destroying the wall colliders?
Why does it detect both the wall and the grunt as a grunt?
How would I go about fixing it?

Here is the script causing the problem:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyProjectile : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    //FIX detects only grunt
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        //Get Tag Component
        Tags hitObject = other.GetComponent<Tags>();

        //Collisions
        if (hitObject.FindTag("boundary"))
        {
            //collision with wall
            Debug.Log("Hit a Wall");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else if (hitObject.FindTag("grunt"))
        {
            //collision with grunt
            Debug.Log("Hit a Grunt");
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(other); //<---- Deletes Boundary Collider (Should be destroying the game object of the grunt, instead destroys the colliders of barriers and the grunt)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the custom tag script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tags : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] startTags;
    private static string[] tags;

    private void Start()
    {
        tags = startTags;
    }

    public bool FindTag(string search)
    {
        bool results = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.Length; i++)
        {
            if(search == tags[i])
            {
                results = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

[Enemy Grunt Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izRpM.png)

[Wall Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhQcf.png)

[Projectile Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwhXV.png)

Comment: Use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)!

Comment: @derHugo I think their design requires that gameobjects can be tagged with a set of tags, instead of exactly one or zero tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it looks you have two problems.

**1)** The first is that your projectile is destroying the collider of the grunt, instead of the grunt. This is because you are passing the collider to the destroy function, not the grunt:

```
Destroy(other);
```

instead use

```
Destroy(other.gameobject);
```

I would also put this before the

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

**2)** Your tag system is not working. My guess is that this is because

```
private static string[] tags;
```

is static. I would remove the static modifier and see if it works. You can also just use `startTags` directly, removing the need for a `start()` assignment.

Unity also, already has a tag system that might be more appropriate for this kind of detection:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html